# Python application in a container using Podman

Tags: python, podman

I'd like to build a container using Podman which would contains the following:

- a Python application
- the Python modules I developed but which are not stored at the same place than the Python application
- the Python environment (made with miniconda/mambaforge)
- a mounted folder for input data
- a mounted folder for output data

To do that, I've added a Dockerfile in my home directory. Below is the content of this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# Add the Python application
ADD /path/to/my_python_app /my_python_app

# Add the Python modules used by the Python application
ADD /path/to/my_modules /my_modules

# Add the whole mambaforge folder (contains the virtual envs) with the exact same path than the local one
ADD /path/to/mambaforge /exact/same/path/to/mambaforge

# Create a customized .bashrc (contains 'export PATH' to add mamba path and 'export PYTHONPATH' to add my_modules path)
ADD Dockerfile_bashrc /root/.bashrc
```

Then, I build the container with:

```
podman build -t python_app .
```

And run it with:

```
podman run -i -t -v /path/to/input/data:/mnt/input -v /path/to/output/data:/mnt/output python_app /bin/bash
```

In the Dockerfile, note I add the whole mambaforge (it is like miniconda). **Is it possible to only add the virtual environment?** I found I needed to add the whole mambaforge because I need to activate the virtual environment with `mamba/conda activate my_env`. Which I do in a .bashrc (with the conda initialization) that I put in `/root/.bashrc`. In this file, I also do `export PYTHONPATH="/my_modules:$PYTHONPATH"`.

I'd also like to add the following line in my Dockerfile to execute automatically the Python application when running the container.

```
CMD ["python", "/path/to/my_python_app/my_python_app.py"]
```

However, this doesn't work because it seems the container needs to be run interactively in order to load the .bashrc first.

All of this is kludge and I'd like to know if **there is a simpler and better way to do that?**

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need to copy the whole environment to your container as you could use pip or conda to generate a new one. Is you python application stored locally on your dev system or available in an online repo? In the first case, you need to copy the required files to the according destinations. If it is available online you can grab the code from your repo (either publicly or with a private access token)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @albert! All is stored locally. I'd like to share my application with others and that they only need to specify the input and output data folders of their machine that would be mounted when running the containing. You mean using conda inside the container? Basically, I'd like to put my application in a container with everything it needs (same env than the one I'm using on my machine) and send it.